# synchronization issue in this Golang program

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a program that functions as a proxy server and can switch over to new endpoint dynamically. but I'm facing a problem that after calling  `switchOverToNewEndpoint()`, there are still some proxy objects connecting to the original endpoint `8.8.8.8` which should be closed.

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

type Proxy struct {
    ID       int32
    From, To *net.TCPConn
}

var switchOver int32 = 0

func SetSwitchOver() {
    atomic.StoreInt32((*int32)(&switchOver), 1)
}

func SwitchOverEnabled() bool {
    return atomic.LoadInt32((*int32)(&switchOver)) == 1
}

var proxies map[int32]*Proxy = make(map[int32]*Proxy, 0)
var proxySeq int32 = 0
var mu sync.RWMutex

func addProxy(from *net.TCPConn) {
    mu.Lock()
    proxySeq += 1
    proxy := &Proxy{ID: proxySeq, From: from}
    proxies[proxySeq] = proxy
    mu.Unlock()

    var toAddr string
    if SwitchOverEnabled() {
        toAddr = "1.1.1.1"
    } else {
        toAddr = "8.8.8.8"
    }
    tcpAddr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", toAddr)
    toConn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    proxy.To = toConn
}

func switchOverToNewEndpoint() {
    mu.RLock()
    closedProxies := proxies
    mu.RUnlock()

    SetSwitchOver()
    for _, proxy := range closedProxies {
        proxy.From.Close()
        proxy.To.Close()
        mu.Lock()
        delete(proxies, proxy.ID)
        mu.Unlock()
    }
}

func main() {
    tcpAddr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", "0.0.0.0:5432")
    ln, _ := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 30)
        switchOverToNewEndpoint()
    }()
    for {
        clientConn, err := ln.AcceptTCP()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        go addProxy(clientConn)
    }
}
```

After thinking for a while, I guess the problem was at

```
    mu.RLock()
    closedProxies := proxies
    mu.RUnlock()
```

But I'm not sure if this was the root cause and if I can fix it by replacing it with the following:

```
    closedProxies := make([]*Proxy, 0)
    mu.RLock()
    for _, proxy := range proxies {
        closedProxies = append(closedProxies, proxy)
    }
    mu.RUnlock()
```

Since the case is hard to reproduce, so could someone with expertise provide an idea or hint? Any comments are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The issues

The change is necessary. In the original implementation, `closedProxies` holds the same map. See this demo:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    proxies := make(map[int]int, 0)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        proxies[i] = i
    }

    closeProxies := proxies

    proxies[10] = 10
    proxies[11] = 11

    for k := range closeProxies {
        delete(proxies, k)
    }

    fmt.Printf("items left: %d\n", len(proxies))
    // Output:
    //   items left: 0
}
```

But this is not the root cause. A new proxy could be added after `closeProxies` is copied but before `SetSwitchOver` is called. In this case, the new proxy connects to the old address but is not in `closeProxies`. I think this is the root cause.

And there is another issue. A new proxy is added to `proxies` before the `To` field is set. It could happen that the program wants to close this proxy before the `To` field is set and result in a panic.

#### A design that works reliablly

The idea is to put all the endpoints into a slice, and let each endpoint manage its own list of proxies. So we only need to keep track of the index of the current endpoint. When we want to switch to another endpoint, we just need to change the index, and tell the outdated endpoint to clear its proxies. The only complicated thing left is to make sure an outdated endpoint can clear all its proxies. See the implementation below:

##### manager.go

This is the implementation of the idea.

```golang
package main

import (
    "sync"
)

// Conn is abstraction of a connection to make Manager easy to test.
type Conn interface {
    Close() error
}

// Dialer is abstraction of a dialer to make Manager easy to test.
type Dialer interface {
    Dial(addr string) (Conn, error)
}

type Manager struct {
    // muCurrent protects the "current" member.
    muCurrent sync.RWMutex
    current   int // When current is -1, the manager is shuted down.
    endpoints []*endpoint

    // mu protects the whole Switch action.
    mu sync.Mutex
}

func NewManager(dialer Dialer, addresses ...string) *Manager {
    if len(addresses) < 2 {
        panic("a manger should handle at least 2 addresses")
    }

    endpoints := make([]*endpoint, len(addresses))
    for i, addr := range addresses {
        endpoints[i] = &endpoint{
            address: addr,
            dialer:  dialer,
        }
    }
    return &Manager{
        endpoints: endpoints,
    }
}

func (m *Manager) AddProxy(from Conn) {
    // 1. AddProxy will wait when the write lock of m.muCurrent is taken.
    // Once the write lock is released, AddProxy will connect to the new endpoint.
    // Switch only holds the write lock for a short time, and Switch is called
    // not so frequently, so AddProxy won't wait too much.
    // 2. Switch will wait if there is any AddProxy holding the read lock of
    // m.muCurrent. That means Switch waits longer. The advantage is that when
    // e.clear is called in Switch, All AddProxy requests to the old endpoint
    // are done. So it's safe to call e.clear then.
    m.muCurrent.RLock()
    defer m.muCurrent.RUnlock()

    current := m.current

    // Do not accept any new connection when m has been shutdown.
    if current == -1 {
        from.Close()
        return
    }

    m.endpoints[current].addProxy(from)
}

func (m *Manager) Switch() {
    // In a real world, Switch is called not so frequently.
    // So it's ok to add a lock here.
    // And it's necessary to make sure the old endpoint is cleared and ready
    // for use in the future.
    m.mu.Lock()
    defer m.mu.Unlock()

    // Take the write lock of m.muCurrent.
    // It waits for all the AddProxy requests holding the read lock to finish.
    m.muCurrent.Lock()
    old := m.current

    // Do nothing when m has been shutdown.
    if old == -1 {
        m.muCurrent.Unlock()
        return
    }
    next := old + 1
    if next >= len(m.endpoints) {
        next = 0
    }
    m.current = next
    m.muCurrent.Unlock()

    // When it reaches here, all AddProxy requests to the old endpoint are done.
    // And it's safe to call e.clear now.
    m.endpoints[old].clear()
}

func (m *Manager) Shutdown() {
    m.mu.Lock()
    defer m.mu.Unlock()

    m.muCurrent.Lock()
    current := m.current
    m.current = -1
    m.muCurrent.Unlock()

    m.endpoints[current].clear()
}

type proxy struct {
    from, to Conn
}

type endpoint struct {
    address string
    dialer  Dialer

    mu      sync.Mutex
    proxies []*proxy
}

func (e *endpoint) clear() {
    for _, p := range e.proxies {
        p.from.Close()
        p.to.Close()
    }

    // Assign a new slice to e.proxies, and the GC will collect the old one.
    e.proxies = []*proxy{}
}

func (e *endpoint) addProxy(from Conn) {
    toConn, err := e.dialer.Dial(e.address)
    if err != nil {
        // Close the from connection so that the client will reconnect?
        from.Close()
        return
    }

    e.mu.Lock()
    defer e.mu.Unlock()
    e.proxies = append(e.proxies, &proxy{from: from, to: toConn})
}
```

##### main.go

This demo shows how to use the **Manager** type implemented before:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net"
    "time"
)

type realDialer struct{}

func (d realDialer) Dial(addr string) (Conn, error) {
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", addr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
}

func main() {
    manager := NewManager(realDialer{}, "1.1.1.1", "8.8.8.8")

    tcpAddr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", "0.0.0.0:5432")
    ln, _ := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)

    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(30 * time.Second) {
            manager.Switch()
        }
    }()
    for {
        clientConn, err := ln.AcceptTCP()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        go manager.AddProxy(clientConn)
    }
}
```

##### manager_test.go

Run the test with this command: `go test ./... -race -count 10`

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func TestManager(t *testing.T) {
    addresses := []string{"1.1.1.1", "8.8.8.8"}
    dialer := newDialer(addresses...)
    manager := NewManager(dialer, addresses...)

    ch := make(chan int, 1)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for range ch {
            manager.Switch()
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    count := 1000
    total := count * 10

    wg.Add(total)

    fromConn := &fakeFromConn{}
    for i := 0; i < total; i++ {
        if i%count == count-1 {
            ch <- 0
        }
        go func() {
            manager.AddProxy(fromConn)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    close(ch)

    wg.Wait()

    manager.Shutdown()

    for _, s := range dialer.servers {
        left := len(s.conns)
        if left != 0 {
            t.Errorf("server %s, unexpected connections left: %d", s.addr, left)
        }
    }

    closedCount := fromConn.closedCount.Load()

    if closedCount != int32(total) {
        t.Errorf("want closed count: %d, got: %d", total, closedCount)
    }
}

type fakeFromConn struct {
    closedCount atomic.Int32
}

func (c *fakeFromConn) Close() error {
    c.closedCount.Add(1)

    return nil
}

type fakeToConn struct {
    id     uuid.UUID
    server *fakeServer
}

func (c *fakeToConn) Close() error {
    if c.id == uuid.Nil {
        return nil
    }

    c.server.removeConn(c.id)

    return nil
}

type fakeServer struct {
    addr  string
    mu    sync.Mutex
    conns map[uuid.UUID]bool
}

func (s *fakeServer) addConn() (uuid.UUID, error) {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()

    id, err := uuid.NewRandom()
    if err == nil {
        s.conns[id] = true
    }
    return id, err
}

func (s *fakeServer) removeConn(id uuid.UUID) {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()

    delete(s.conns, id)
}

type fakeDialer struct {
    servers map[string]*fakeServer
}

func newDialer(addresses ...string) *fakeDialer {
    servers := make(map[string]*fakeServer)
    for _, addr := range addresses {
        servers[addr] = &fakeServer{
            addr:  addr,
            conns: make(map[uuid.UUID]bool),
        }
    }
    return &fakeDialer{
        servers: servers,
    }
}

func (d *fakeDialer) Dial(addr string) (Conn, error) {
    n := rand.Intn(100)
    if n == 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("fake network error")
    }
    // Simulate network latency.
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(n) * time.Millisecond)

    s := d.servers[addr]
    id, err := s.addConn()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    conn := &fakeToConn{
        id:     id,
        server: s,
    }
    return conn, nil
}
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation. regarding how to fix the root cause. do u think if I can fix it by putting `SetSwitchOver()` ahead of `closeProxies`?

Comment: It will cause a new issue. Imagine that after a proxy is added to `proxies` and before the statement `if SwitchOverEnabled() {` is reached, `switchOverToNewEndpoint` is called and it switches to the new endpoint. Now the new proxy is in `closeProxies` but it connects to the new endpoint.

Comment: @HFX I have updated the answer to add my suggested design that should address the issue. Please note that I haven't tested the code. Please edit the answer or comment if you find any obvious errors. Thank you!

Comment: @HFX I have refactored the implementation to make it testable and added test case to make sure it works as expected. Please take another look. Thank you!

Comment: appreciate it. I learned a lot from you. I like the idea of struct `endpoint`, which separates proxies from different endpoints. so we can easily manage the proxies connecting to the old endpoint.